# Casting a String to a Number in generic class

Tags: java, generics, casting, javafx-2

I have a class meant for holding numeric values that could be changed by the user through the GUI. The GUI has a TextField (of JavaFX) where they could write the desirable value.

Since I wanted this class to be flexible I made it using generics like this:

```
public class ConfigurableNumericField <T extends Number> {

    private T value;
    //...
    public void setValue(T value){ 
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

And I create an object like this:

```
ConfigurableNumericField <Integer> foo = new ConfigurableNumericField <> ( /*...*/ );
```

The problem is that the TextField returns a `CharacterSequence` (that could be casted to `String`). BUT even if all classes that inherit from `Number` have the `valueOf` method, `Number` does not have it.

So when I try to `setValue()` the `String` from the TextField to the class itself. I get a `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When generics you can make things so generic that they are not meaningful anymore.

In your case you need a setValue which will take a String so you can convert it to the appropriate type. The problem with this is there is no way to do this genericly as the generic type of `foo` is not available at runtime.

I would have two subclasses, one for integers which uses a `Long` and another which uses a `Double` or `BigDecimal`.  This will support most of the Number types you are likely to need.

Answer (score 1):

You really can't.  All of the possible approaches end up involving special cases for each number type.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this may be problematic is that future / custom `Number` implementations may not provide this method, since it's not part of the contract.

Here are two options that comes to mind:

- Use reflection to invoke the `setValue` method.
- Use a couple of `instanceof` checks and casts to cover the Numbers you need to support.

Comment: The problem with `instanceof` is that you don't know the generic type at runtime.

Comment: Can't you do `if (value instanceof Long) ...` etc?

Comment: You can. In this case the value in this case is a `String` and the `Number` type you need to convert it to is unknown at runtime.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `if (this.value instanceof Long) ...`.